# How to show needed row in UIPickerView?

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I have known data in array and I need to show selected row when my app loaded. How can I select "Four", for example, at the start?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zIs5.png)

```
let arrayOfNumbers = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerTest.delegate = self
    pickerTest.dataSource = self
}

@IBOutlet weak var pickerTest: UIPickerView!

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfNumbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return arrayOfNumbers[row]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pickerTest.selectRow(4, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

Comment: Omg!
It was so easy... 
Thank you!